# How to implement without Nested IF conditions in android

Tags: java, android

In the below code I had nested if conditions and want to avoid multiple else if condition.

Can anyone suggest me any other way we can implement and cleaner code?

```
if (advance_value_power_save_after != 0 && advance_value_power_off == 0 && advance_value_grid == 0 && advance_value_aux == 0 && advance_dim_dispaly == 0 && advance_fast_charge == 0) {
    pesManager.advanceSettingsPowerSaveAfterCommand(advance_value_power_save_after);
} else if (advance_value_power_save_after == 0 && advance_value_power_off != 0 && advance_value_grid == 0 && advance_value_aux == 0 && advance_dim_dispaly == 0 && advance_fast_charge == 0) {
    pesManager.advanceSettingsPowerOffCommand(advance_value_power_off);
} else if (advance_value_power_save_after == 0 && advance_value_power_off == 0 && advance_value_grid != 0 && advance_value_aux == 0 && advance_dim_dispaly == 0 && advance_fast_charge == 0) {
    pesManager.advanceSettingsGridCommand(advance_value_grid);
} else if (advance_value_power_save_after == 0 && advance_value_power_off == 0 && advance_value_grid == 0 && advance_value_aux != 0 && advance_dim_dispaly == 0 && advance_fast_charge == 0) {
    pesManager.advanceSettingsAuxCommand(advance_value_aux);
} else if (advance_value_power_save_after == 0 && advance_value_power_off == 0 && advance_value_grid == 0 && advance_value_aux == 0 && advance_fast_charge == 0 && advance_dim_dispaly != 0) {
    pesManager.advanceSettingsDimDisplay(advance_dim_dispaly);
} else if (advance_value_power_save_after == 0 && advance_value_power_off == 0 && advance_value_grid == 0 && advance_value_aux == 0 && advance_dim_dispaly == 0 && advance_fast_charge != 0) {
    pesManager.advanceSettingsFastChargeMode(advance_fast_charge);
} else {
```

Comment: Use Switch instead

Comment: @Murtaza with Hash map is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 if (advance_value_power_off == 0 && advance_value_grid == 0 && advance_value_aux == 0 && advance_dim_dispaly == 0 && advance_fast_charge == 0) {
    if (advance_value_power_save_after != 0) {
        pesManager.advanceSettingsPowerSaveAfterCommand(advance_value_power_save_after);
    } else if (advance_value_power_off != 0) {
        pesManager.advanceSettingsPowerOffCommand(advance_value_power_off);
    } else if (advance_value_grid != 0) {
        pesManager.advanceSettingsGridCommand(advance_value_grid);
    } else if (advance_value_aux != 0) {
        pesManager.advanceSettingsAuxCommand(advance_value_aux);
    } else if (advance_dim_dispaly != 0) {
        pesManager.advanceSettingsDimDisplay(advance_dim_dispaly);
    } else if (advance_fast_charge != 0) {
        pesManager.advanceSettingsFastChargeMode(advance_fast_charge);
    }
}
```